# django cms copy translated pages from dev serv to prod serv

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-cms

Django cms can be as powerful as buggy sometimes.

Thus my company just hired some translators and they worked on the development serveur.

They translated a lot of pages from english to turkey, spanich, french...
That's why I am asked to find a way to copy those pages to the production server.

I am not completely at ease yet with back-end stuff and after reading this subject :

[copy pages from dev to prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603036/how-can-i-copy-cms-pages-from-a-development-site-to-a-live-site)

I feel less comfortable haha.

Isn't a way to copy pages excluding one language (the main one actually : english) 'easily' ?

Thank you in advance for the time spent on my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need is in the database, so some kind of export from dev & import to production is what you'll need.

Usually when I'm preparing a site in dev for production release I'll do a full export, sanitize any data, remove anything not needed then import to production. It's easier doing things that way, especially dealing with multiple languages because of the way CMS divides up content for pages between multiple tables.

For example, all the page settings are kept in `cms_title` and links back to the `cms_page` table where there's a copy of each page per language. Because you've got a page per language then you'll usually find the plugin's store everything in the same table, so the text plugin has it's `djangocms_text_ckeditor_text` table which stores all your translated content in the one place.

You might be best exporting all the content tables you need from the CMS & plugins, like `cms_cmsplugin`, `cms_page`, `cms_title`, `djangocms_text_ckeditor_text`, etc. Then import them to a local database to test and/or modify any content before it ends up on your production server.

Comment: Yeah, the translation arrived after the deployment !
Yeah someone explained me how to export / import postgres tables, this is such a big help.

Comment: But I have to thank you a lot because you are explaining where the data can be stored for a specific page. 
I appreciate the time you spent in this answer. Furthermore it's helping, nice :D